# Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'xxx' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OF

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have checked all the topics on this error with entitframework but I can't find my issue.

I use entityframework core.

I have an accomplishment and a criteriagroup in the accomplishment class.

When I save for the first time the accomplishment everything works.

Then when I want to update it I gave the error "Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in CriteriaGroups Table...

```
 "name": "Accomplishment1",
    "criteriaGroupId": 4,
    "categories": [],
    "criteriaGroupFk": {
        "gOperator": 0,
        "criterias": [],
        "groups": [],
        "id": 4
    },
    "id": 2
}
```

The class model of the accomplishment is:

```
[Table("Accomplishments")]
public class Accomplishment : AuditedEntity 
{

    [Required]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual int? CriteriaGroupId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CriteriaGroupId")]
    public CriteriaGroup CriteriaGroupFk { get; set; }

    public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }

}
```

The class for the criteriagroup is as below:

```
    [Table("CriteriaGroups")]
public class CriteriaGroup : CreationAuditedEntity 
{

    public virtual GroupOperator GOperator { get; set; }

    public List<Criteria> Criterias { get; set; }

    public List<CriteriaGroup> Groups { get; set; }
}
```

In my code I see that it goes to update the accomplishment object. But I think that entityframework sees the criteria group as new even if it has an id.

What's wrong with it?

I struggle since 2 days on it.

```
private async Task Update(CreateOrEditAccomplishmentDto input)
     {
        var accomplishment = await _accomplishmentRepository.FirstOrDefaultAsync((int)input.Id);
         ObjectMapper.Map(input, accomplishment);
         await CurrentUnitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
     }
```

Comment: Where is the property for the Id of CriteriaGroup table?

Comment: It's in the creationauditedentity it has a property int id.

Comment: If your goal is to update accomplishment do not pass  createriagroupfk ot set it to null. If you want to update both record at the same time, that doesnt supportedby ef . https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=3&ved=2ahUKEwjl4-iT_rTlAhVukIsKHYMyA2IQFjACegQICRAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F42735368%2Fupdating-related-data-with-entity-framework-core&usg=AOvVaw14P0WHwx2cNNu8b1Gz37kU

Comment: It should also update criteriagroup because I will modify it. How can I set to entityframework it's an update and not a new insertion? The id is not null or equal to 0 so I don't understand.

Comment: Could you please include the code you use to perform the update?

Comment: I updated the question with the detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure to not overwrite the `CriteriaGroup` with an untracked object, because in this case the `CriteriaGroup` is considered new.

The described issue could happen if for example you don't load the related `CriteriaGroupFk` when loading the `Accomplishment`, and afterwards assigning an untracked object to `CriteriaGroupFk`.
To resolve the issue you can use [Include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.include), e.g.:

```
var accomplishment = await _accomplishmentRepository.Include(x => x.CriteriaGroupFk).FirstOrDefaultAsync((int)input.Id);
```

See [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) and [Tracking vs. No-Tracking Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking)
 for further information.